# Navigating in slidify presentation

Tags: r, slidify

I have created a HTML5 presentation with [slidify](http://slidify.org/) using the io2012 framework.

I am actually struggling with the navigation inside the presentation:

1. is there a way to link between slides, e.g. jump back to slide x from slide y? I know I can do this with HTML but maybe there is a better solution?
2. how can I embed a control panel in the slides so that users can click on an arrow to go to the next slide?